# Getting "eval" operator to add multiple inputs (corresponds to "int" values)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I apologize for the poor formatting. This is my first time posting

```
SERVICE_WASH=50 #$50.00 is cost to wash carpet
SERVICE_DUST=15 #$15.00 is cost to dust house
SERVICE_SEAL=70 #$70.00 is cost to stain seal floors
SERVICE_ODOR=35 #$35.00 is cost for odor removal service


SERVICE_TYPE = eval(input("What services would you like for the rooms\nSelect using numbers from below (ex. 2,4,1):\n\n1-Carpet Wash\n2-House Dusting\n3-Stain Seal\n4-Odor Removal\n\n"))        
print()

if SERVICE_TYPE=={}:
SERVICE_TYPE["1"]=SERVICE_WASH
SERVICE_TYPE["2"]=SERVICE_DUST
SERVICE_TYPE["3"]=SERVICE_SEAL
SERVICE_TYPE["4"]=SERVICE_ODOR

print("Your total today will be", ((ROOM_NUM)*(SERVICE_TYPE)),"Thank you!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `eval`. You can store the multiple inputs after splitting the original user input. Also you need to have the dictionary variable and user input variable name different.

Once you have the different user input service types stored, you can iterate over the dictionary and store the corresponding charges and at last sum them up.
Try this :

```
SERVICE_TYPE = {
    '1' : SERVICE_WASH, 
    '2' : SERVICE_DUST, 
    '3' : SERVICE_SEAL, 
    '4' : SERVICE_ODOR,
}
SERVICE_ = input("What services would you like for the rooms\nSelect using numbers from below (ex. 2,4,1):\n\n1-Carpet Wash\n2-House Dusting\n3-Stain Seal\n4-Odor Removal\n\n")

# If you expect multiple values to be space separated
SERVICES = SERVICE_.strip().split()
CHARGES = [SERVICE_TYPE[i] for i in SERVICES]
print(f"Your total today will be {sum(CHARGES)}. Thank you!")
```